# DATEADD When Dealing with SmallDateTime Data Type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

What I'm trying to accomplish is to select all records in a table that were created the previous day - and the record is stored in the table as a 'smalldatetime' so it also includes the time the record was created.

[image: CreatedDateTime]

If I used the DATEADD function in my WHERE clause, I am returning no records which I know is incorrect.

`Appt.CreatedDateTime = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())`

How I can strip off the time stamp to find all records that were created the previous day?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options here. You can cast your column as a DATE or you can do some date math.

```
where Appt.CreatedDateTime >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) --beginning of yesterday
    and Appt.CreatedDateTime < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) --beginning of today
```

OR

```
CAST(Appt.CreatedDateTime as DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: While both work, you should prefer the former option if you value good index use.

Comment: Actually casting a datetime to a date is one of those funky times it doesn't render the query nonSARGable. I prefer the more verbose option though because it is very clear that it is SARGable. :D

Comment: interesting... thanks for the tip!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659476/castdatetime-as-date-over-where-clause

Comment: And casting to date isn't as optimal as the `>=...<` http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/3690

Comment: Yeah that is exactly why I listed it first. That is an excellent writeup there @MartinSmith.

Comment: Thanks  I'll check both of these out tomorrow.