# Using dash while using like in where clause in SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table including such data in SQL Server 2008:

```
id  TimeStamp
--------------------------
1   2016-02-19 11:52:01 AM
2   2016-02-21 11:30:05 AM
```

I am trying to select such data saved in the date 19 February 2016. I am using the query in the below, but it is returning result without any values.

```
select * 
from myTable 
where [TimeStamp] like '2016-02-19%'
```

However, when I write the query below, I can get all the data saved in 2016. So I believe something is wrong with the dashes maybe?

```
select * 
from myTable 
where [TimeStamp] like '%2016%'
```

How can I fix my issue, what is my error?

Comment: use `where [TimeStamp] >= '2016-02-19' and [TimeStamp] < '2016-02-20'`

Comment: If you want to keep the LIKE then convert it to varchar.

Comment: the answer to this SO may be interesting to you as it compares execution plans to some of the methods below.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659476/castdatetime-as-date-over-where-clause  using a date range >= date < date+1 is proposed as the best.  I myself like the use of CAST(date as Date) which performs pretty well too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `like` with dates.  Use simple comparisons:

```
where [TimeStamp] >= '2016-02-19' and [TimeStamp] < '2016-02-20'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
where cast([TimeStamp] as date) = '2016-02-19'
```

Answer (score 0):

use  [CONVERT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT * from myTable where CONVERT(NVARCHAR,[TimeStamp],112) =  '20160219'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to use the "like" command convert the data data to varchar.  Either solution will work.